# How do I find the largest integer less than x?

Tags: python, math, floating-point

If `x` is `2.3`, then `math.floor(x)` returns `2.0`, the largest integer smaller than or equal to `x` (as a float.)

How would I get `i` the largest integer *strictly* smaller than `x` (as a integer)?

The best I came up with is:

```
i = int(math.ceil(x)-1)
```

Is there a better way?

Note, that if `x` is `2.0` then `math.floor(x)` returns `2.0` but I need the largest integer smaller than `2.0`, which is `1`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the largest integer smaller or greater than x"?

Comment: @komaromy: OP probably means "smaller or equal".

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No, it behaves differently if `x` is integral.

Comment: If x is 2.0 then math.floor(x) returns 2.0 but I need the largest integer smaller than 2 which is 1. int(math.ceil(x)-1) returns 1.

Comment: If the input value is negative, what do you want?  For -1.2, you want -2; for -2.0, you want -3.0?

Comment: I think your original choice of `int(math.ceil(x) - 1)` is the right one

Comment: int(math.ceil(x))-1 seems the best. Better than my int(math.ceil(x)-1) anyway. So @Kevin should get the check mark for right answer.

Comment: If using Python 3, it's just `math.ceil(x) - 1`. This further emphasises that it's the right choice. Although you should really use `int(math.ceil(x)) - 1` on Python 2 for accuracy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`math.ceil(x)-1` is correct and here is the proof.

if `x` is in **Z** (the set of integers), then `math.ceil(x)` = `x`.  Therefore `math.ceil(x)-1`=`x-1`, the largest integer smaller than `x`.

Else we have `x` in **R** \ **Z** and `math.ceil(x)` is the smallest integer `y` such that `x` ≤ `y`.  But then `y-1` is an integer smaller than the smallest integer such that `x` ≤ `y`, therefore `x` > `y-1` and by construction `y-1` is the largest such integer smaller than `x`.

It's simple enough that I wouldn't bother with those `if`-`else`.  But to avoid computation errors with floats I would do the `-1` outside the `int` conversion.

```
int(math.ceil(x))-1
```

Comment: Marked this as the best answer, although Kevin suggested it first. This discussion was very interesting.

Comment: The conversion to `int` is only required for floats greater in magnitude than `2.0**53`. As an example where it is required, try `9007199254740996.0`

Answer (score 1):

The following C code works in a certain sense---it gives you the next most negative integer that's representable as a floating-point number:

```
double flooor(double x) {
  return floor(nextafter(x, -1.0/0.0));
}
```

The following Python code is a direct transliteration, but it relies on NumPy:

```
def flooor(x):
  return math.floor(numpy.nextafter(x, -numpy.inf))
```

The `nextafter` function moves from its first argument one `double` closer to its second argument.  It has a special case; if `z < 0` and you ask for `nextafter(0.0, z)`, it will return the smallest negative subnormal number.

From your specification, it is unclear what should be done with positive infinity and the most negative finite number.  This code sends positive infinity to the most positive finite number, negative infinity to itself, and the most negative finite number to negative infinity.

Martijn Pieters gave the incantation `int(math.ceil(x)) - 1` in his answer, since deleted.  This correctly finds the largest `int` less than the `float` `x`.  This rounds `x` up, converts it to integer, and subtracts 1, giving the largest Python `int` that is numerically less than `x`.

Comment: @AerofoilKite: Done.  But I'd note that it's not hard to call C code from python.

Comment: can you explain why my answers are wrong? For my knowledge

Comment: @AerofoilKite: Useful test cases: `1.7976931348623157e+308`, `1.7976931348623155e+308`, `1267650600228229401496703205376.0`, and their negatives.

Comment: @tmyklebu: e.g. `sys.float_info.max`, for which `int(math.ceil(x)) + 1` returns the *next valid integer*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Why'd you take down your answer?

Comment: @tmyklebu because with several downvotes people clearly didn't think it to be helpful. I didn't have the time to expand it further so I took it down.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Pity.  I'll expand mine to cover the "next smallest bigint" problem.

Answer (score -2):

What about:

```
i = int(math.floor(x) - 1)
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  Subtracting 1 is a no-op for sufficiently big floating-point numbers.

Comment: Even after floor? I tried the cases you provided and it seems to work.

Comment: If `x = 1267650600228229401496703205376.0`, you get `i = 1267650600228229401496703205376`.

Comment: x = 1267650600228229401496703205376.0, 
    i = int(math.floor(x) - 1),
    i,
1267650600228229401496703205375

Comment: Weird.  That's not what happens here running python 2.7.9.

Comment: Yes, it works in 3.4 but not in 2.7. If you know any documentation about this let me know, i'm new with python as you can see.

Comment: It appears that `math.floor` returns `int` in Python 3 but `float` in Python 2.  Ugh.